# PhpStorm does not recognize my models in the app folder

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am using Laravel 7. I use PhpStorm, and great fan of it.

I want to store all of my model files in a single folder named `Models` into `app` folder. I changed this line:

```
namespace App; -> namespace App/Models.
```

But PhpStorm is giving me an error. It doesn't recognize my folder:

> Undefined constant 'Models'

How can I fix this?

[image: the error photo]

Comment: use `App\Models` not `App/Models`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the anti slash for namespace

```php
namespace App\Models;
```